# Call setListAdapter from a different class file

Tags: android, android-asynctask, listadapter

I have a class file like this:

```
public class Search_Results extends SherlockListActivity{

     String result = "";
     SearchView searchView;
     Context context = this;
     private Intent intent = null;
     private String searchThis = "";

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
             setTheme(R.style.Sherlock___Theme_DarkActionBar);
             setContentView(R.layout.search_results);
             ListView myList=(ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
             ProgressBar progress = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progress_spin);
             intent = getIntent();
             searchThis = intent.getStringExtra(Home.SEARCH_SERVICE);
             new Retrieve(context, progress, searchThis, myList).execute("");
      }//onCreate
}
```

This calls new `Retrieve()` that's on another java file and extends `AsyncTask`

```
public class Retrieve extends AsyncTask <String, Integer, ArrayList<String>>{

     private Context context;
     private String title = "";
     private ArrayList<String> list = null;
     private ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = null;
     private String result = "";
     private ProgressBar progress;
     private String searchThis;
     private ListView mylist;

     //constructor
     public Retrieve(Context context, ProgressBar progress, String searchThis, ListView myList) {
         this.context = context;
         this.progress = progress;
         this.searchThis = searchThis;
         this.mylist = myList;
     }
protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(String... params){
            progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            InputStream is = null;
            list = new ArrayList<String>();
            nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("searchThis", searchThis));
            try{
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URL);
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("CONNECTION_ERROR", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
            }
            try{
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                result=sb.toString();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("BUFFER_ERROR", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
            }
            if(result.equalsIgnoreCase("null\n")){
                list.add("empty");
            }
            else{
                try{
                    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                    for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                        JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        title = json_data.getString("title");
                        list.add(title);
                    }
                }
                catch(JSONException e){
                    Log.e("DATA_PARSING_ERROR", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
                }
            }
            return list;
        }

     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> list){
         progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         ArrayAdapter<String> mArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, R.layout.list_display, list);
         //PROBLEM
         mylist.setAdapter(mArrayAdapter);
     }

 }//Retrieve
```

I first tried only `setListAdapter(mArrayAdapter)` but obviosly java doesn't know wich list to update, then i tried passing the list to the constructor doing

```
ListView myList=(ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

And I get this error:

```
android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: 
Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

Maybe because I'm trying to change a view from another class? How can I solve this issue? Should the `onPostExecute` function return the `mArrayAdapter`? How can this be accomplished?

Comment: post your doInBackground method code

Comment: I'll edit the code in the morning because I don't have it with me right now.

Comment: ok because u have problem inside doInBackground instead of onPostExecute

Comment: I edited the code for the doInBackground function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are getting `Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.` because you are trying to access UI elements from doInBackground . so just move it outside from doInBackground and move it inside onPreExecute as :

```
 @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
         progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //<< set here
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want to create the adapter and set it in your Search_Results activity. The adapter for a list should be a component of the Activity the list is in. You want to avoid tightly coupling your UI with an AsyncTask like this, i.e. your `Retrieve` class just needs to do work and return, not know the details about what happens with the data it gets.

I would create a public method in Search_Results, (say, `updateAdapter`) that you can call from the `onPostExecute` method. You can call it from the `context` member variable of your `Retrieve` class:

```
public void updateAdapter(ArrayList<String> list) {
    ArrayAdapter<String> mArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Search_Results.this, R.layout.list_display, list);
    setListAdapter(mArrayAdapter);
}
```

And in `onPostExecute`:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> list){
    progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    context.updateAdapter(list);
}
```

Comment: Your solution seems the most elegant, I have a problem though, `context.updateAdapter(list);` eclipse tells me that the method is undefined for the type Context and as suggestion to make a cast to a Context variable, I tried to pass the context both as this and as Search_Results.this.

Comment: You might be able to cast the 'context' variable to an Activity, i.e. Activity activity = (Activity) context; then call activity.updateAdapter(list);

Comment: Ok thanks, a question though, shouldn't the JVM be able to recognize that I'm calling the function that exists into another class since I explicitly set the context?

Comment: I think it has to do with it being set as a 'Context' object, not explicitly an 'Activity'. The method you are trying to call is only available at the Activity level and is not a method of the Context class. So you need to explicitly cast it. And upon review (my previous comment was rushed) I think you need to cast to the specific 'Search_Results' activity instead of the more generic 'Activity'.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `ListActivity` object instead of `ListView` to your `Retrieve` constructor.